# Selenium WebDriver not recognizing an element, tried many options

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium web driver but have successfully written a couple of Junit tests using it so far. I am now on my third test and running into an issue where an element cannot be found. I am getting the error "`NoSuchElementException`" from Selenium. I have spent hours trying many options (see below).

In short, the product I am testing goes to a third party product, to be exact it connects with Google Cloud Storage. The page giving issues is actually a page written by Google so I can't talk to the developer to see if frames were used and I can't tell from the html however there is a gray section called 'framebuster code' so possibly there are frames? (see below).

I did try to specify that there was an `iframe` by using "`driver.switchTo().frame(0);`"

but that didn't work either.

Lastly, the element I am trying to find is momentarily grayed out while the page is loading. I tried an implicit wait, 
"`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`"

But that didn't help.

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong or more suggestions to try would be greatly appreciated. I can't let this beat me. :-)

Here are all of the options I tried. Note the first option came from IDE and it works fine in IDE just not through the WebDriver.

```
`driver.findElement(By.id("submit_approve_access")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Accept')])")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("submit_access")).click();
driver.findElement(By.className("goog-buttonset-action")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=submit_name]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='goog-buttonset-action']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText(“Accept”)).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='goog-buttonset-action']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text() = ‘Accept]”)).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[tabindex='1']")).click();`
```

Below is the html from the page (note: the element I am looking for is denoted with * on the line. I have also tried some of the hidden items from the line above it as well.):

`

```
<head></head>
<body>
    <noscript></noscript>
    <!--

     framebuster code starts here 

    -->
    <style></style>
    <script></script>
    <xmp style="display:none"></xmp>
    <!--

     framebuster code ends here 

    -->
    <div id="ogb"></div>
    <div id="third_party_info_container">
        <div id="third_party_info" class="section_container" data-section="main">
            <div class="column"></div>
            <div id="approval_container">
                <div class="column">
                    <div id="connect_container" class="modal-dialog-buttons button_container">
                        <form id="connect-approve" style="display: inline;" method="POST" action="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=32b8da86447…d=none&xsrfsign=APsBz4gAAAAAVLBpqOjvhQOwuPvNvPdcZF53EntxeTvP">
                            <input id="bgresponse" type="hidden" name="bgresponse"></input>
                            <input id="_utf8" type="hidden" value="☃" name="_utf8"></input>
                            <input id="state_wrapper" type="hidden" value="CoYDcmVzcG9uc2VfdHlwZT1jb2RlJmFjY2Vzc190eXBlPW9mZmxpbmUmcmVk…UucmVhZF9vbmx5EhUxMTY5MjAyNTM4Nzc2NTMxNzA1MTQY7seC5-zsnJbqAQ" name="state_wrapper"></input>
                            <input id="submit_access" type="hidden" value="" name="submit_access"></input>
                            *<button id="submit_approve_access" class="goog-buttonset-action" tabindex="1" type="submit"></button>
                            <button id="submit_deny_access" tabindex="2" type="submit"></button>
                        </form>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:none"></div>
    <div id="tooltip_bubble"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <iframe src="https://clients5.google.com/pagead/drt/dn/" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></iframe>
</body>
```

`

Comment: Have you tried an explicit wait using `WebDriverWait`?

Comment: Thanks @alecxe, using WebDriverWait I am getting a timeout. Selenium just can't see the button. I am continuing to be baffled however though all the help, I have learned more about Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are no iframes in this code but I think you should try

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button#submit_approve_access")).click();
```

This will find the button with the id "submit_approve_access".
If you are looking for the input element then try

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#submit_access")).click();
```

And if that does not work the last thing I can think of is this

```
(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#submit_access"))).click();
```

These extra brackets make sure that .click is performed on an object. It should not make a difference but it might.

Also about the greyed out element you should not use the implicit wait code. That is for when you use

```
driver.get("");
```

Try:

```
try{
Thread.sleep(500);
}catch(Exception e){//Use this before you find the element
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Instead of:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: @ColdConfusion, Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried all of the above but unfortunately they do not work either.

Comment: @ColdConfusion, To be more specific I am getting "NoSuchElementException" then when I use the sleep I am getting a timeout. I am now thinking there is something odd about this page or different from other pages since this page is evoked through using Google API's from our product.

Comment: Huh that is very odd. Oh well that's pretty much all I know. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I learned a lot from you for future Selenium tests. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `explicit` wait. Another piece of info if you are using `ie` there is a known issue if you have take [KB 3025390] update (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8302)

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("submit_approve_access")));
driver.findElement(By.id("submit_approve_access")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Saifur. I am getting a java.lang.AssertionError:timeout when using the webdriverwait. Selenium Webdriver just doesn't see the button.

Comment: Then the click won't work either becacause `selenium` won't interact with hidden element unless you execute `javascript`. Can you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: Below is the full stack trace (I have to split it since it is too big as a single comment):  
`java.lang.AssertionError: timeout
 at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
 at ConnectAppsOAuthTest.connectAppsJunitTest(ConnectAppsOAuthTest.java:100)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)`

Comment: ' at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
`

Comment: ` at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
`

Comment: ` at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)`

Comment: `java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.AssertionError
 at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
 at ConnectAppsOAuthTest.tearDown(ConnectAppsOAuthTest.java:141)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
`

Comment: ` at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
`

Comment: ` at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
`

Comment: ` at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
`

Comment: What browser are you in?

Answer (score 0):

Always before clicking on any element you should wait for the presence of that element you can use following piece of code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Flow.timeOutLimit);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("submit_approve_access")));          
driver.findElement(By.id(submit_approve_access)).click();
```